# cucumber + selenium: functional tests & testing content

Tags: selenium, architecture, cucumber, functional-testing

I'm frontend developer and currently I'm working in a company that we are in the process of automating our multilanguage website. We have implemented sentences to mock the services that uses the platform, sentences that represents actions of user, and other sentences to check the content depending on actions.

I would ask about these last referred sentences. Our architecture team has decided to do features with sentences like:
'In the page it must be displayed de text "acme city sample"'

If you look, the sentence does not talk about any element of the page. The test will be true if this text exists in any place of page. The architects don't like to use any type of css selector to locate elements because they say that is a functional test and we are testing only that we are able to see in the output of browser. So, all of kind of references of selectors are forbidden. We only use xpath to find elements that contains the required text and then we check that these elements are displayed. Another reason to defend this point of view is that in this way you reduce the coupling between the website project and automation project.

However, this decision seems too much restrictive for me. For example, It is difficult to check content that is sorted by some criteria.

But I would like to know what do you think about this and, if you have had another experiences, how did they use to test the content of a website? However, if you thought that is a good decision, I'd be interested in reading some reference or  article to understand because this is the best way to test the content.

Comment: If you must test sorting in a result set, you must be able to verify this in English. In that case you should be able to verify in an alternate language that has alternate terms for a sortable enum-type field (like status field).

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few issues here that need to be addressed.

**Implementation Language**

> In the page it must be displayed de text "acme city sample"

I assume this means that your cucumber script equivilent looks like this:

```
Then In the page it must displayed de text "acme city sample"
```

(if this is not the case let me know and I will correct it
This is not the correct way to write a statement for BDD. In BDD you want to have the general behavior mapped out as oppose to the specific "implementation Language". A better way of writing this would be:

```
Then I should receive information relevant to "acme city sample"
```

In this way you decouple your expected output from any implementation. In this way if the expected output changes from text to, lets say, an image. You're overall behavior for your end user isn't changing, its just how they consume the info. So I would suggest first removing all implementation language.

Examples of implementation language are:

- Click
- Type
- Select
- Move

There may be situations where you will still need to use these, but in general avoid them.

**Avoiding all selectors in preference of xpath**

I've seen a lot of people do this for some reason and I can never really understand why.  First of all using a CSS selector you can do the same as xpath and be more efficient. I would look into doing that if possible.

> we are testing only that we are able to see in the output of browser.

--

> Another reason to defend this point of view is that in this way you
>   reduce the coupling between the website project and automation
>   project.

This is not a reason to not use selectors. xpath is still a selector. I assume you are doing this to quickly find the text on the page. Assuming you know 100% you will never get a false positive, then I can understand why you are doing this however understand that this in no way reduces coupling. What happens if your Acceptance Criteria changes from text to image? Your Tests will always be coupled to the project, there is no way around that. What you need to ask yourself is, does using xpath only give me a result I am confidant in, and is it easy to implement or change as needed. Does it cover the Acceptance Criteria we wrote earlier?